# Payflow checkout error - "Invalid merchant information: 10002"

Tags: php, paypal, payflowpro

I have properly setup a payflow hosted checkout page as seen in this image:

[image]

This requires credentials and those credentials are properly configure to gain the secure token posted from Paypal.

My issue is when I checkout with any credit cards I get:

> ["RESPMSG"]=> string(85) "Invalid merchant information: 10002-You do
>   not have permissions to make this API call"
>
> ["RESULT"]=> string(1) "5"

I know that there is nothing wrong with my code, and as I said before, credential are not wrong, because I was able to setup a new payflow account and able to checkout without any problems.

Can someone help me get to the bottom of this?

Transaction are recorded in the payflow but returns the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes most probably because of the sandbox account attached to your Manager account . You need to make sure that you have attached a Business Pro sandbox account in your manager account under "Service Settings --> Set Up --> PayPal Sandbox Email address".